# Strings.xml is named in different ways

Tags: android

I would like to know the difference between the following

```
values-b+de
```

and

```
values-de
```

Comment: Is what you have shown here the name of the file or the directory it is in.

Comment: see https://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/languages.html

Answer (score 0):

These both folders are used for localization. The way that you have implemented both values folder will be select the country code of the "de" language.

In `values-b+de` folder you are passing the language code as null so it will select the default language code and in `values-de` you are the call for default language code.

Creating the directory, the format is as below.

```
<resource type>-b+<language code>[+<country code>]
```

For more details, you can go to this [link](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/languages.html#CreateDirs)

Answer (score 0):

Actually there is not difference between them as you write them.
The values-b convention was introduced in Android 7 (API level 24) in order to Improve the resource-resolution strategy as mentioned here:
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/multilingual-support.html#postN

And here also:
https://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/languages.html#CreateDirs

Example:

For Spanish in general you will have resources in values-b+es folder.
But if you want these resources to make influence only for Spanish in Latin america you will have to place you're resources in values-b+es+419 (which was values-es-rUS in the old convention).